# Can I still modify and update my app's metadata after submitting the app for review?

Tags: metadata, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I just submitted my app for getting reviewed. Now I want to do tiny tweaks to my app's metadata, is it still allowed? I tried doing it and then Save on the changes, it's always timedout for the few times that I tried. So I wonder if it's because that the further changes are not allowed after submitting an app for review. Can anyone please confirm/explain?

Answer (score 2):

You used to be able to change the metadata (e.g., screenshots) even after the app is approved, but not anymore.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may change your metadata up until the point that it is "In Review". Once the app is approved, you may change the metadata except for the keywords.